# The fire keeper's eyes (alternate ending)

Tags: dark-souls-3

I am playing the new game+ on Darksouls 3, and I want to try one of the alternate ending;

> where you give the fire keeper in firelink shrine the "fire keeper's eyes" item, and then you don't link the final fire after you defeat the Soul of Cinder for one of the alternate endings.

My question is: if you choose this ending, are there any permanent repercussions to doing this, or does it just affect the ending to the current game you are playing? I looked around for the answer to this online, but couldn't find any information.

Comment: By "permanent repercussions", do you mean "repercussions that will carry into the next NG"?

Comment: yes , I mean exactly that. Repercussions that carry into the next game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ending that you choose has no effect on anything in your next New Game. I've played through the game four times, each with a different ending, and my choices never affected anything in the subsequent new games.

For more information on what does and does not carry over into NG(+), see the [Fextralife wiki](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/New+Game+Plus).

Comment: Thank you for the answer Pushasha. I will go for it and not link the fires. l have two more endings to discover. DarkSouls3 rocks!